# Autodesk forge design automation civil 3d

Tags: autodesk-forge

Unable to read C3D objects with design automation API. I am able to extract civil 3d objects from the cad file and save the information as a text file on my local machine. But when we use AutoCAD design Automation  engine Autodesk.AutoCAD+24 it does not provide us the data that we need. It use to work before, also we were using the Autodesk.AutoCAD+24  engine on several application we have online to extract and analyze civil 3d objects and they stop functioning properly.

Even though the status of the report says successful, it does not mean that the civil 3d objects were extracted or even read properly.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod... ",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-10-22T20:10:07.8093412Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-10-22T20:10:07.9675172Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2020-10-22T20:10:10.0892293Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2020-10-22T20:10:22.9818639Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2020-10-22T20:10:23.1051272Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1093711,
    "bytesUploaded": 4141
  },
  "id": "d8e7600d6ae84651bd76dd58906dc7a4"
}
```

We get an error shown below.

```
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] ************************MessageBox****************************
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] Exception in t:\aces\acesroot\24.0\coreengine\exe\aeccdbmgd.dll ARX Command
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] Unhandled Exception e0434352 (e0434352h) at address 2a2096c9h
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] >>>Responding: OK.

[10/22/2020 20:10:21] **************************************************************
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] ************************MessageBox****************************
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] Exception in t:\aces\acesroot\24.0\coreengine\exe\aeccdbmgd.dll ARX Command
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] Unhandled Exception e0434352 (e0434352h) at address 2a2096c9h
[10/22/2020 20:10:21] >>>Responding: OK.
```

I am still trying to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed this post. It looks same to what you have posted with forge.help  as ticket #7631. I will update this SO post after we complete the discussion in #7631

Comment: Update: resolved by using Design Automation of Civil3D. Thanks @ehermoso